# Überbegriff für "zurück-wischen" und "zurück-drücken"

Tags: single-word-request

Ich bin dabei, eine Android-App zu warten.
Wie viele andere Apps auch hat sie folgendes Feature:

Wenn der Nutzer den "Zurück"-Button drückt, obwohl er nicht weiter zurück navigieren kann, erscheint ein PopUp (toast):

> Bitte erneut drücken um die App zu beenden

Bisher war das völlig in Ordnung, allerdings verändert sich das Navigationskonzept mit Android-Version 10.
Statt einem Zurück-Button gibt es nun (auch) eine "Zurück-Wisch-Geste".

Für beide Varianten möchte ich eine einheitliche Formulierung verwenden.
Meine bisher beste Lösung ist

> Führe die Aktion erneut aus, um die App zu beenden

Allerdings finde ich, dass "eine Aktion ausführen" (zu?) sehr nach "tiefer in die App eintauchen" klingt. Vorschläge?

Comment: Was ist wenn der User erst zurück wischt und dann den Zurückbutton drückt? Dann führt er eine andere Aktion aus, aber ich nehme mal an, die App soll sich trotzdem beenden. Das würde "Aktion erneut ausführen" nur noch halb richtig gestalten, weil die andere Möglichkeit ignoriert wird.

Comment: Das sieht mir eher nach einem Programmier- als nach einem sprachlichen Problem aus.  Ist zu dem Zeitpunkt denn nicht klar, welche Aktion vorher ausgeführt wurde? Was passiert denn, wenn ich doch nicht beenden will? Wie wäre es denn mit dem guten, alten *Wirklich beenden?* - *Ja/Nein*, wobei sowohl *zurück-wischen* als auch *zurück-drücken* ebenfalls zum Beenden führt?

Comment: @infinitezero Soweit ich weiß, kann ein Nutzer nur eine von beiden Bedienungsarten aktiviert haben.

Comment: @Olafant Vermutlich lässt sich diese irgendwie durch Code erfragen, allerdings würde ich diese zusätzliche Komplexität gerne vermeiden.
Die Antwort auf die zweite Frage ist: toast. Das ist ein unaufdringlich aufploppendes Fenster. Bei diesem hat der Nutzer keine Möglichkeit zur Interaktion. Es verschwindet nach kurzer Zeit automatisch.
Aber "Wirklich beenden?" gefällt mir +1

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's more about programming than about the German language.

Comment: You might want to consider asking this on UI stackexchange.

Comment: Bei einer "wirklich beenden" - Frage erwarte ich aber eine Antwortmöglichkeit ja/nein, nicht, dass ich dich letzte Aktion wiederholen soll. Dass man auch die alternative ausüben könnte mag sein oder nicht - das kann man m.E. als spitzfindig unterschlagen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eine kurze, dafür weniger eindeutige Variante:

> Zum Beenden wiederholen

oder:

> Zum Beenden erneut berühren

Das setzt zwar voraus, dass der oder die Benutzende weiß, was er vorher gemacht hat – aber gerade das soll ja bestätigt werden.

Answer (score 3):

Neben der Formulierungsänderung verwendet der letzte Vorschlag auch den Imperativ statt des Infinitivs. In Deutschen ist der Infinitiv allgemein gebräuchlicher, und für den begrenzten Informationsstand der App (ob der Benutzer die App tatsächlich beenden will oder nicht, kann bestenfalls vermutet werden) auch deutlich eher angebracht.

Mein Vorschlag:

> Erneutes Durchführen der letzten Aktion beendet die App

oder mit Infinitiv:

> Zum Beenden der App letzte Aktion wiederholen

Falls *letzte Aktion* zu allgemein klingt, kann man auch ein neuen Begriff wie *zurückgehen* verwenden, darin dürften sich beide Methoden wiederfinden.

Answer (score 0):

Da diese Frage im Sprachforum steht, möchte ich sie auch von der sprachlichen Seite her beantworten.

Ich finde auch dass "Aktion ausführen" unpassend klingt. Ich bezweifle dass man so schnell erkennt was die App damit aussagen möchte.
*Aktion? Was ist damit gemeint?*

> Vorschläge?

Für einen gemeinsamen Überbegriff habe ich keinen Vorschlag, da fällt mir nichts passendes ein, das beide Vorgänge gleichzeitig erkennbar beschreibt.

Für die gesamte Situation an sich hätte ich einen: verwende zwei getrennte Formulierungen.
Wenn Zurück gedrückt wurde: **Zum Beenden erneut drücken**
Wenn gewischt wurde: **Zum Beenden erneut wischen**

Aus sprachlicher Sicht ist das eindeutig und sauber beschrieben.
Viel besser als *"mache das selbe nochmal"*.

Ich würde die App übrigens nur dann beenden wenn die selbe Geste zweimal durchgeführt wurde. Alles andere ist nicht schlüssig sondern vielmehr verwirrend.
Überhaupt könnte es eher unerwartet statt hilfreich sein, wenn man die App durch zwei verschiedene Gesten beenden kann. Hier gilt das selbe wie bereits beim sprachlichen, eine App die zu sehr von gewohntem Verhalten abweicht, wird möglicherweise als seltsam empfunden.

Answer (score -1):

Ein weiterer Vorschlag wäre

> zurücknavigieren